# Why does a homogenous system Ax = 0 with nontrivial solution imply that A is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Fact: A linear equation will have a non-trivial solution if and only if A is singular.**

How do I think about this statement geometrically, in terms of transformation?

Suppose A is a matrix that describes some transformation.
The solution to the homogenous system Ax = 0 is then the set of all vectors that get mapped to the zero vector upon the transformation of A.

If Ax = 0 has only non-trivial solution, why must that imply that A is singular?

Comment: What is your definition of a singular matrix?

Comment: ummm.. you seem to demand that $A$ be square

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel of $A$ is not trivial, then it is not injective. So, it is not invertible. Hence, $\det{A}=0$.